# Check if View controller class exists in array of view controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am trying to check a list of view controllers from `self.navigationController.viewControllers`.

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.navigationController.viewControllers, nil];
```

As an example this would return an array like this:

```
array -- (
        (
        "<HomeViewController: 0xb1aca10>",
        "<LeftMenuViewController: 0xe751520>"
    )
)
```

I am now needing to check if HomeViewController exists in the array how do I do this?

I have tried to do `[arrayOfControllers containsObject:[MESHomeViewController class]])` but this does not return true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Loop through all your view controllers and check if the view controller is `[MESHomeViewController class]`. You do not need an instance of MESHomeViewController to use this method.

```
for (UIViewController *vc in arrayOfControllers) {
    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[MESHomeViewController class]]) {
        //It exists
    }
```

Comment: This doesnt appear to work, the exists part is not being called even though I know the class exists in the array per the question/log

Comment: Fixed it by creating the initally array correctly - NSMutableArray *arrayOfControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];

Answer (score 1):

`containsObject` requires that you pass a specific instance, not just the type of class you wish to find. If you have a reference to the specific MESHomeViewController, pass that as the parameter to `containsObject:`.

Comment: Beat me by 50 seconds, but yes. This is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
[arrayOfControllers containsObject:[MESHomeViewController class]]
```

Will not work because a pointer to the controller is in the array, not the class name of the controller.

You should be able to simply do

```
[arrayOfControllers containsObject:self] // if inside MESHomeVIewController
[arrayOfControllers containsObject:myHomeViewController] //The instance of MESHomeViewController
```

Edit:

If you don't want to allocate the class to check, you could use the isKindOfClass: checks or instead create an array with the class names instead of the actual instances

Comment: What if I do not have an instance of the home controller? Would I have to alloc/init just to check if it exists, which in turn creates the controller in the background just for a check... if so this is not what I would want to do as its a large VC

Comment: Two solutions I can think of -
The first one is the solutions using isKindofClass:
The second one is to create an array using the classes instead of the objects

Comment: The way you're creating the array of view controllers assumes the controller you're testing for has been created and exists in self.navigationController.viewControllers.  Also, there is something fishy about what you're doing if you need to check the existence of something that doesn't exist yet...no?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a loop and test with `isKindOfClass:`